# Trying to identify this bush

Tags: identification

Trying to see if I can trim this bush and not kill it. Located in eastern TN.  It's probably 10 feet tall and the leaves turn red in the fall,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even without a clear identification, I would dare to claim that it is trimable, assuming you don’t just take a chainsaw to it and cut it all the way down. Do you have a specific target for trimming, e.g. reducing the volume or rejuvenating? I wouldn’t necessarily just shorten the branches.

Comment: If you can add a better photo on the flowers (if there are still some open). Are the seeds like green peas?